# How to make tkinter scale run a command when user scrolls?

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

I need to run a command when the user scrolls a tkinter Scale widget. Luckily, it has a handy option `command`. So when I create it I can do:
`bar = tk.Scale(master, command=myCommand)`

However, the one problem is when I try to set the scale value using `bar.set()`, it also runs the command which I don't want. So, how can I get the scale to run its command **only** when the user scrolls it, not when I set it?

Comment: You can use a flag that you set just before you call `bar.set()` and reset when you are done. You can make `myCommand` act differently according to the flag

Comment: Can you show your code?